# Sublime Text 2 - не компилируется Java-код

Tags: java, компиляция, sublime-text

ОС: Windows 7 64bit.
Поставил последнюю Java 7 SE, Sublime Text 2.
Прописал path, CLASSPATH
Создал в ST2 простейший кусок кода (типа helloworld). Выбираю тип билда - javac, нажимаю - Build - задержка в 4 секунды и все. В папке с test.java не появляется файл test.class. Если же запускаю cmd.exe - пишу там javac test.java - все прекрасно компилируется и создается файл test.class.
Искал логи в ST2 - но не нашел, где же затык?

Comment: поставь нормальное ИДЕ

Comment: ну если проблема не решится - поставлю. но пока осваиваю java - тренируюсь где попроще - чтоб руку набить

Answer (score 1):

В **Preferences->Browse Packages->Java->JavaC.sublime-build** посмотри.

[Документация](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html?highlight=build) к этому.

Comment: да, там тоже смотрел - там стартует javac. т.е. все нормально

Comment: Вот что пишет лог ST2:
Running javac D:\Java\test.java
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
  File ".\exec.py", line 154, in run
  File ".\exec.py", line 45, in __init__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

Причем тут ascii кодировка?

Comment: Возможно у вас в программе русские символы в пути.Или вот обратите внимание,[решение][1] аналогичной проблемы.
  [1]: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8512

Хотя и вправду лучше использовать IDE,например IntelliJ IDEA.